# Validation using testinstalledbasic function in R

Tags: r, validation

I am trying to test my R installation but I am having issues. Running the below code in 5 different machines:

```
> Sys.setenv(LC_COLLATE = "C", LANGUAGE = "en")  
> library("tools")
> testInstalledBasic("both")
```

Gives the following message:

> running regression tests   running code in ‘reg-tests-1a.R’   running
>   code in ‘reg-tests-1b.R’   running code in ‘reg-tests-1c.R’   running
>   code in ‘reg-tests-2.R’   comparing ‘reg-tests-2.Rout’ to ‘reg-tests-2.Rout.save’ ...7256c7256
>
> ### <   ï..ColA ColB ColC
>
> > X...ColA ColB ColC Warning message: running command 'diff -bw "C:\Users\xd00010\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSSTr6F\Rdiffa2140205053b0"
> >     "C:\Users\xd00010\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSSTr6F\Rdiffb2140c9a5185"'
> >     had status 1

The issue seems to be my machine reads the "UTF-8-BOM" file with the **ï** symbol but the reference file in "R" tests has **X** instead. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a bit forward but now have new issues. Here is the solution if anyone needs it:

```
options(encoding = "UTF-8")  
Sys.setenv(LC_COLLATE = "C", LANGUAGE = "en",LC_TIME="C",LC_CTYPE="C")
library("tools")
testInstalledBasic("both")
```